# How can I change my gnome-terminal title?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, gnome, gnome-terminal

Previously I changed my gnome-terminal title to display which server I was logged into. I don't remember how I did this and I can't change it now.

I ran through my .bashrc and found nothing that would set it, and logged in as su. As superuser the title also changes.

I checked my .Xdefaults file... nothing

I tried to open a gnome terminal with:

```
gnome-terminal --title=$PWD
```

Any title I set with the above command or PROMPT_COMMAND will be shown for half a second and then revert to my server name.

I looked through the terminal settings too. Any thoughts where I could have made this change? Running on CentOS.

Comment: What's your `PS1` variable?

Comment: Here it is:

    [16:08]~>echo $PS1
    \[\e]2;\h\a\][\A]\W>\[\e[0m\]

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "MyWindowTitle"
```

to note - you need the **wmctrl** package first.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/22838)

You can find more possible solutions at the given source.

Comment: Stop apologizing for short answers --  this is plenty adequate IMO. :)  But, if you _really_ don't feel you have the time to post a decent answer, please just don't post one.  :)

Comment: Same problem, the title will flash "MyWindowTitle" and then go right back to the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably using [shell escape codes](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html) like this:
`echo -ne "\033]2;hello\007"`
This will set the terminal title to be `hello`. And from the description I'd guess that you are doing something like this:
`gnome-terminal -> shell(e.g. bash) -> ssh user@othermachine -> bash`
In that case, you need to search for it on the local machine, might be something bash or ssh is doing.

Comment: Yes, this would probably be better off as a comment on the question, but since I'm not allowed to comment on other thing than my own, this had to be an answer.